# How do I create a document set in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I've been following the steps listed on this site: https://sharepointmaven.com/document-sets-hidden-gem-sharepoint/ & others, however I cannot find the "Site Collection Administration" and "Site Collection Features" where the ability to activate documents sets is said to be. Here are my views when I click on my site settings: [Site Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4b7AQ.png) and [Document Library Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PNCO.png)

I've dug around for quite a while within the SharePoint settings. This process seems like it should be relatively basic, so I know I'm missing something. I appreciate any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not have administrator permissions to see site settings/site collection settings. These are hidden for normal users.